# horizontal line graph with assambly in R

Tags: r, graph, line, ggplot2, lattice

I have big data like the following but this just little sample.

```
pos <- c(1, 3, 5, 8, 10, 12)
start <- c(1,3, 6, 7, 10, 11)
end <- c(5, 6, 9, 9, 13, 12)
```

Qunatative variable Pos will be Y axis and X axis will be anthor X variable (quantitative). The horizontal bar length for each Pos value is defined by start and end point. For example,line for 1 will start from 1 and end at 3 in x axis.

The following is rough sketch of desired the figure output.

[image]

Comment: Is the last example helpful? http://had.co.nz/ggplot2/geom_linerange.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use package `ggplot2` with `geom_segment` to draw the lines.

Start by combining your data into a `data.frame`, since this the required data structure for `ggplot`:

```
dat <- data.frame(
  pos = c(1, 3, 5, 8, 10, 12),
  start = c(1,3, 6, 7, 10, 11),
  end = c(5, 6, 9, 9, 13, 12)
)
```

Create the plot:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(dat) + 
    geom_segment(aes(x=start, y=pos, xend=end, yend=pos), color="blue", size=3) +
    scale_y_reverse()
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

In base R...

```
plot(pos, type = 'n', xlim = range(c(start, end)), ylim = c(13,0))
grid()
segments(start, pos, end, pos)
```

To get it more exactly like your figure...

```
r <- par('usr') 
plot(pos, type = 'n', xlim = range(c(start, end)), ylim = c(13.5,0.5), xlab = '', 
    xaxt = 'n', yaxt = 'n', panel.first = rect(r[1], r[3], r[2], r[4], col = 'goldenrod'))
# abline(h = 1:13, col = 'white')
# abline(v = 1:13, col = 'white')
grid(lty = 1, col = 'white')
axis(1, 1:13, 1:13, cex.axis = 0.8)
axis(2, 1:13, 1:13, las = 1, cex.axis = 0.8)
segments(start, pos + 0.5, end, pos + 0.5, lwd = 2)
```