# plot overlapping positions from different files in R

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, lattice

I have a two big files with `Start` and `End` positions and two sample columns (numeric).

`File 1:`

```
Start  End  Sample1  Sample2
1         60      1       4
100       200     2       1
201       250     1       4
300       450     1       1
```

`File 2:`

```
Start  End  Sample1  Sample2
40         60      1       1
70        180      1       1
240       330      2       1
340       450      1       4
500       900      1       4
980       1200     2       1
```

First, I would like to take the first `Start` and `End` positions from first file and make a segment plot. The plot must also take into account `Start-20` and `End+20` for each position in first file.

Then I would like to take the **overlapping** `Start` and `End` positions from the second file and plot it on the above plot. In this way there will be many plots based on the `Start` and `End` positions from the first file and the one with out overlaps will also be plotted individually.

The `color` for each segment will be based on the two sample numbers (for example in both the files if its `1 and 4` the color of segment will be `red`, if its `1 and 1` the color of segment will be `green` and so on).

I would really appreciate if someone make me understand how to make function for this in R.

Thanks in advance.

PS I have attached the drawing for an[image] output. I have shown only two results.

Below is the code which I wrote but it gives an error

**Error in match.names(clabs, names(xi)) :
  names do not match previous names**

Also I need to specify red color to dataset1 line segment and green color to 
dataset2 line segments. How will I implement it in the code below?

```
overlap_func <- function(dataset1,dataset2) {

for(i in 1:nrow(dataset1))
 {

 loop_start <- dataset1[i,"Start"]
 loop_end <- dataset1[i,"End"]
 p <- dataset2[,c(1,2)]   
 dataset1_pos <- data.frame(loop_start,loop_end)
 dataset2_filter <- p[p$Start >= (loop_start-(loop_start/2)) & p$End <= (loop_end+ (loop_end/2)), ]
 data_in_loop <- rbind(dataset1_pos,dataset2_filter)
 plot_function(data_in_loop,loop_start,loop_end)

 }
 }


plot_function <- function(loop_data,start,end){ 
 pos <- 1:nrow(loop_data)
 dat1 <- cbind(pos,loop_data)
 colnames(dat1) <- c("pos","start","end")
 pdf(file=paste0("path where plots are generated","_",start,"-",end,"_","overlap.pdf"))
 plot(dat1$pos, type = 'n', xlim = range(c(start-(start/2), end+(end/2))))
 segments(dat1$start, dat1$pos, dat1$end, dat1$pos)
 dev.off()
 }


df1 <- read.table(header=T, text="Start  End  Sample1  Sample2
1         60      1       4
100       200     2       1
201       250     1       4
300       450     1       1")

df2 <- read.table(header=T, text="Start  End  Sample1  Sample2
40         60      1       1
70        180      1       1
240       330      2       1
340       450      1       4
500       900      1       4
980       1200     2       1")

 overlap_func(df1,df2)
```

Comment: Can you roughly show how the output would look like (by painting on some software or scanning a drawing out of paper?). It seems interesting to me and I'd love to try it, but it is ambiguous (or  complicated) to know exactly what you're looking for.

Comment: Why this is donwvoted! +1

Comment: (+) here too. @agstudy, No idea.

Comment: @glow I don't know what a segment plot is. A quick google turned up lots of different candidates. Can you enlighten us?

Comment: @SlowLearner, I was assuming [**this**](http://docs.ggplot2.org/0.9.3/geom_segment.html)

Comment: @Arun I am drawing plot.

Comment: @SlowLearner by segment plot I meant horizontal line graph [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9432488/horizontal-line-graph-with-assambly-in-r)

Comment: @Arun Please see the uploaded drawing

Comment: @glow, I'm a bit confused as I thought you were using the `ggplot2` solution??

Comment: @Arun Yes I was using that but its little bit complicated so I have generated my own code. Please look at the code and error above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this??

```
df1 <- read.table(header=T, text="Start  End  Sample1  Sample2
1         60      1       4
100       200     2       1
201       250     1       4
300       450     1       1")

df2 <- read.table(header=T, text="Start  End  Sample1  Sample2
40         60      1       1
70        180      1       1
240       330      2       1
340       450      1       4
500       900      1       4
980       1200     2       1")

require(IRanges)
require(ggplot2)
require(plyr)

df1$id <- factor(1:nrow(df1))
ir2 <- IRanges(df2$Start, df2$End)
out <- ddply(df1, .(id), function(x) {
    ir1 <- IRanges(x$Start, x$End)
    o.idx <- as.data.frame(findOverlaps(ir1, ir2))$subjectHits
    df.out <- rbind(x[, 1:4], df2[o.idx, ])
    df.out$id1 <- x$id
    df.out$id2 <- seq_len(nrow(df.out))
    df.out
})
out$id1 <- factor(out$id1)
out$id2 <- factor(out$id2)
out$id3 <- factor(1:nrow(out))

p <- ggplot(out, aes(x = Start, y = id3 , colour = id2)) 
p <- p + geom_segment(aes(xend = End, ystart = id3, yend = id3))
p <- p + scale_colour_brewer(palette = "Set1")
p
```

[image: gglot2_no_facet_geom_segment]

**Edit:** After looking at your updated drawing, maybe this is what you want?

```
p + facet_wrap( ~ id1, scales="free")
```

[image: ggplot2_facet_geom_segment]

**Edit:** Save each plot in facet in separate file. You can do this by generating the plot each time by splitting on `id1`

```
d_ply(out, .(id1), function(ww) {
    p <- ggplot(ww, aes(x = Start, y = id3 , colour = id2)) 
    p <- p + geom_segment(aes(xend = End, ystart = id3, yend = id3))
    p <- p + scale_colour_brewer(palette = "Set1")
    fn <- paste0("~/Downloads/id", as.numeric(as.character(ww$id1[1])), ".pdf")
    ggsave(fn, p)
})
```

Set the path in `fn` accordingly.

Comment: @agstudy, it produces the same colours (at least in this case). However, the way OP declares colours is a bit confusing. If it's `1 and 4` in both files -> one entry in `file1` may have more overlaps in `file2` and each of them `may/not` have the same combination(this part is not clear).

Comment: looks like the OP don't like your answer ?:)

Comment: How so? There are probably some modifications to be made. Somethings are unclear to me. So I dint implement them. I guess this is a good place to start though.

Comment: yes. personally I find it good. I already upvote. any comments on my solution is welcom.

Comment: @Arun Thanks for the solution!! I was wondering If there is any way for drawing each plot in to separate pdf files.

Comment: @glow, you really take your time to reply! I've forgotten about this post and what I did! :) I'll take a look at it and reply asap.

Comment: @Arun Sorry for that I was very busy in making other plots :)

Comment: @glow. You mean each of the 4 plots that are facetted in different pdf files?

Comment: yes exactly. This was just a dummy data. when I  am using the code on the big data then all the line segments are getting shrink.

Comment: @glow, check the edit at the bottom of this post. And if this answers your question, please mark it as such by checking the tick mark located underneath the answer score.

Answer (score 1):

I tried to solve this problem using `lattice` package. I specially use function `Shingle` to get an idea of the intervals to compare. I hoped I can merge the 2 shingles but I can't. So, once I have a my first plot, I used ( as in the above solution) `IRanges` package to compute the overlaps. The idea is have a final `dotplot`.

```
## I red the input data
dat <- read.table(text = 'Start  End  Sample1  Sample2
1         60      1       4
100       200     2       1
201       250     1       4
300       450     1       1', header = T) 

dat1 <- read.table(text = 'Start  End  Sample1  Sample2
40         60      1       1
70        180      1       1
240       330      2       1
340       450      1       4
500       900      1       4
980       1200     2       1', header = T) 


## I create my 2 shingles
dat.sh <- shingle(x = dat[,3], intervals = dat[,c(1,2)])
dat1.sh <- shingle(x = dat1[,3], intervals = dat1[,c(1,2)])
## compute max value for plot comparison
max.value <- max(c(dat$End,dat1$End))
## I plot the 2 series with differents color
p1<- plot(dat.sh, xlim= c(0,max.value),col = 'red')
p2 <- plot(dat1.sh,xlim= c(0,max.value), col ='green')
library(gridExtra)
grid.arrange(p1,p2)
```

This is a fast method to compare my intervals.

[image]

This looks Ok, but I can't go further with shingle since I can't merge them in the same plot. SO I will use `IRanges` package to compute the overlaps.

```
library(IRanges)
rang1 <- IRanges(start=dat[,1], end = dat[,2])
rang2 <- IRanges(start=dat1[,1], end = dat1[,2])
dat.plot     <- dat1                    # use the first data.frame
dat.plot$group <- 'origin'
dat.plot$id <- rownames(dat1)           ## add an Id for each row
rang.o <- findOverlaps(rang2,rang1)     # get overlaps
dat.o <- dat1[rang.o@queryHits,]        ## construct overlaps data.frame 
dat.o$id <- rang.o@subjectHits
dat.o$group <- 'overlap'
dat.plot <- rbind(dat.plot,dat.o)      ## union of all 
dotplot(id ~End-Start|group  , data=dat.plot, 
                               groups = col,type = c("p", "h"))
```

[image]

Comment: (+1) by why the dot plot at the end? can't you group the overlaps together?

Comment: I thought the dotplot is convenient to see multiple overlaps. see the 4the segment for example. and I don't know the equivalent of geom_segment using lattice :)